# Installing SQL 2012 Express Using Configuration.ini file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a configuration.ini file so I can do a quiet install of SQL 2012 Express.  I installed the full version far enough to get the configuration file.

Every time I run my batch file that calls the config file I get the following error at the end of my Detail.txt

(01) 2014-03-07 13:21:42 Slp: Setup result: 0
(01) 2014-03-07 13:21:42 Slp: SQM Service: Sqm does not have active session.

I am using a new PC with Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2010 installed.

This is my configuration file - can anyone see what I am missing.

> (01) 2014-03-07 13:21:42 Slp: Setup result: 0 (01) 2014-03-07 13:21:42
>   Slp: SQM Service: Sqm does not have active session.
>
> > ;SQL Server 2012 Configuration File [OPTIONS]
>
> ; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE.
>   This is a required parameter.
>
> ACTION="Install"
>
> ; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined
>   yet.
>
> ENU="True"
>
> ; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values
>   are Normal for the full UI,AutoAdvance for a simplied UI, and
>   EnableUIOnServerCore for bypassing Server Core setup GUI block.
>
> ; Setup will not display any user interface.
>
> QUIET="True"
>
> ; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction.
>
> QUIETSIMPLE="False"
>
> ; Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover and include product
>   updates. The valid values are True and False or 1 and 0. By default
>   SQL Server Setup will include updates that are found.
>
> UpdateEnabled="True"
>
> ; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of
>   top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL
>   feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and
>   Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install
>   Management Tools, Books online components, SQL Server Data Tools, and
>   other shared components.
>
> FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,FULLTEXT,RS,BIDS,CONN,BC,SDK,BOL,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,LOCALDB
>
> ; Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will obtain product
>   updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid
>   folder path, a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC share. By
>   default SQL Server Setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows
>   Update service through the Window Server Update Services.
>
> UpdateSource="MU"
>
> ; Displays the command line parameters usage
>
> HELP="False"
>
> ; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the
>   console.
>
> INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
>
> ; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line
>   argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system.
>
> X86="False"
>
> ; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.  This
>   directory remains unchanged after shared components are already
>   installed.
>
> ; INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> ; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared
>   components.  This directory remains unchanged after WOW64 shared
>   components are already installed.
>
> ; INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> ; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default
>   instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions.
>   This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database
>   Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS).
>
> INSTANCENAME="MyInstance_12" SAPWD="MyPasswordr3r443r43r3$$" ; Specify
>   the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL
>   Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will
>   incorporate the instance ID of the SQL Server instance.
>
> INSTANCEID="INTEGRATED_3D_12"
>
> ; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent
>   to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable
>   this feature.
>
> SQMREPORTING="False"
>
> ; RSInputSettings_RSInstallMode_Description
>
> RSINSTALLMODE="DefaultNativeMode"
>
> ; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL
>   Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable
>   this feature.
>
> ERRORREPORTING="False"
>
> ; Specify the installation directory.
>
> INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> ; Agent account name
>
> AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
>
> ; Auto-start service after installation.
>
> AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
>
> ; CM brick TCP communication port
>
> COMMFABRICPORT="0"
>
> ; How matrix will use private networks
>
> COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"
>
> ; How inter brick communication will be protected
>
> COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"
>
> ; TCP port used by the CM brick
>
> MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"
>
> ; Startup type for the SQL Server service.
>
> SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
>
> ; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3).
>
> FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"
>
> ; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express.
>
> ENABLERANU="True"
>
> ; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the
>   Database Engine.
>
> SQLCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"
>
> ; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account.
>
> SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$INTEGRATED_3D_12"
>
> ; Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server system administrators.
>
> ; The default is Windows Authentication. Use "SQL" for Mixed Mode
>   Authentication.
>
> SECURITYMODE="SQL"
>
> ; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for
>   SQL Server 2012 Express.
>
> ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"
>
> ; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol.
>
> TCPENABLED="0"
>
> ; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol.
>
> NPENABLED="0"
>
> ; Startup type for Browser Service.
>
> BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
>
> ; Specifies which account the report server NT service should execute
>   under.  When omitted or when the value is empty string, the default
>   built-in account for the current operating system. ; The username part
>   of RSSVCACCOUNT is a maximum of 20 characters long and ; The domain
>   part of RSSVCACCOUNT is a maximum of 254 characters long.
>
> RSSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\ReportServer$INTEGRATED_3D_12"
>
> ; Specifies how the startup mode of the report server NT service. 
>   When  ; Manual - Service startup is manual mode (default). ; Automatic
>   - Service startup is automatic mode. ; Disabled - Service is disabled
>
> RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
>
> ; Add description of input argument FTSVCACCOUNT
>
> FTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$INTEGRATED_3D_12"
>
> IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"

Comment: Solved, if anyone needs help i'll post my file

Comment: Please could you post your .ini file and the command line used to run.

Comment: Hi Me_JF, can you please post me your solved file